# Laravel Searching returns all data instead of wanted data

Tags: php, laravel

My search functionality uses laravel. Whenever I'd search something, instead of returning the wanted result, it returns all the data within the database. For eg: if I searched 'a', it will return all data from the database.

My Search form is

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0" action="/search" method="GET">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Search.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    @if($search->isNotEmpty())
        @foreach ($search as $searched)
            <div class="post-list">
                <p>{{ $searched->filename }}</p>
                <p>{{ $searched->albumname }}</p>
                <p>{{ $searched->artistname }}</p>
    @endforeach
    @else 
        <div>
            <h3>No songs/artist/albums found</h3>
        </div>
    @endif
@endsection
```

Search routing

```
Route::get('/search', [UploadController::class,'search']);
```

UploadController.php

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $searching = $request->input('search');

        // $posts = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1])
        $search = MusicUpload::query()
                ->where('filename','LIKE',"%{$searching}%")
                ->orWhere('artistname','LIKE',"%{$searching}%")
                ->orWhere('albumname','LIKE',"%{$searching}%")
                ->get();
        
        return view('pages.search',compact('search'));
    }
```

I think there is problem with the upload query in the controller, but I haven't found out the exact place where the problem occurs.

Comment: If you search 'a'... Literally 'a'? what does `dd($searching)` output?

Comment: name parameter missing in input tag, <input name='search' type="text"> in form then you can get the value like $request->get('search')

Answer (score 1):

You must out `or` queries in callback - call-back here like a braces in sql query.

Or you can put this query to scope:

```
class MusicUpload extends Model
{
  public function scopeSearch($query, $search)
  {
     return $query->where(function($query){
        $query->where('filename','LIKE',"%{$searching}%")
            ->orWhere('artistname','LIKE',"%{$searching}%")
            ->orWhere('albumname','LIKE',"%{$searching}%");
     
     });
  }
}

$searching = $request->input('search');
$search = MusicUpload::search($searching)->get();
return view('pages.search',compact('search'));
```